# C# console call sharepoint online rest api with credentials problem

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-rest-api, credentials

My goal is to call REST API and retrieve specific folder and files metadata to specific site. I wrote a console application in C#. The SharePoint site is multi-factor enabled and I can get the site lists in success:

```
var authenticationManager = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();
ClientContext context = authenticationManager.GetWebLoginClientContext(@"https://XXX-admin.sharepoint.com/", null);
GetAllSiteCollections(context);
```

However I have no idea why I get credential error when calling function GetFilesPropertiesFromSite:

```
Message: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
InnerException: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.IdcrlException: Identity Client Runtime Library (IDCRL) could not look up the realm information for a federated sign-in.
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlAuth.GetUserRealm(String login)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlAuth.GetServiceToken(String username, String password, String serviceTarget, String servicePolicy)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.SharePointOnlineAuthenticationProvider.GetAuthenticationCookie(Uri url, String username, SecureString password, Boolean alwaysThrowOnFailure, EventHandler`1 executingWebRequest)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials.GetAuthenticationCookie(Uri url, Boolean refresh, Boolean alwaysThrowOnFailure)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineAuthenticationModule.GetSpoAuthCookieAndUpdateRequest(WebRequest request, SharePointOnlineCredentials spoCredentials, Boolean preAuthentication)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineAuthenticationModule.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest request, ICredentials credentials)
at System.Net.AuthenticationManagerDefault.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest request, ICredentials credentials)
at System.Net.AuthenticationState.AttemptAuthenticate(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest, ICredentials authInfo)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmitForAuth()
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmit(Exception& e, Boolean& disableUpload)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.DoSubmitRequestProcessing(Exception& exception)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.ProcessResponse()
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponse(CoreResponseData coreResponseData)
```

Code:

```
private static void GetFilesPropertiesFromSite()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter admin username: ");
                string username = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter password: ");
                string password = Console.ReadLine();

                var Uri = new Uri(@"https://XXX.sharepoint.com/sites/AL/");
                var credentials = PrepareSPOCredentials(username, password);
                var result = ExecuteSearchRequest(Uri, credentials, "contentclass:STS_ListItem AND ContentType:Task");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Message: " + ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("InnerException: " + ex.InnerException);
            }
        }

        private static SharePointOnlineCredentials PrepareSPOCredentials(string userName, string passWord)
        {
            var securePassWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (var c in passWord.ToCharArray()) securePassWord.AppendChar(c);
            var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassWord);
            return credentials;
        }
```

Do anyone has the same issue before? Please give me some comment/sample code. Appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could call rest with Credential in SPO like this:

```
 private async Task test()
        {
            Task<string> getStringTask = getWebTitle("https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/");
            string data = await getStringTask;

        }
        private static async Task<string> getWebTitle(string webUrl)
        {
            //Creating Password 
            const string PWD = "xxx";
            const string USER = "xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com";
            const string RESTURL = "{0}/_api/web?$select=Title";

            //Creating Credentials 
            var passWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (var c in PWD) passWord.AppendChar(c);
            var credential = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(USER, passWord);

            //Creating Handler to allows the client to use credentials and cookie 
            using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = credential })
            {
                //Getting authentication cookies 
                Uri uri = new Uri(webUrl);
                handler.CookieContainer.SetCookies(uri, credential.GetAuthenticationCookie(uri));

                //Invoking REST API 
                using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(string.Format(RESTURL, webUrl)).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    string jsonData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    return jsonData;
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using username format first.last@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com instead of first.last@mytenant.com.

Comment: Thanks, but it throws the error: `The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system.`
The account is just the site administrator. Is it necessary to use global admin to call API?

Comment: @Angela How you over come this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if Legacy Auth aka Basic Auth is disabled at your tenant. If it is disabled then get it enable for this account.